# How to deploy Angular app under container of nginx?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm trying to deploy Angular app under docker Nginx. My config is next:

./Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS builder
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", "./"]
RUN yarn install --production=false
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/angular-nginx/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

./nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

The app works, but its assets like images doesn't load (On development assets works).

[image]
[image]

And if I try to access directly to http://localhost:4000/assets/img/logo.png always go to http://localhost:4000/

What is my mistake?, thank you very much for the help.

[image]

Comment: could you provide the folder structure inside of dist/angular-nginx/ ?

Comment: @Andrei I add the folder structure, check please

Comment: The `try_files` line is confusing things: if a file is missing, even if it's supposed to be an image, it's serving up the contents of the `index.html` page successfully rather than sending a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is probabably in this command

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/angular-nginx/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

should be

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/angular-nginx/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

with your variant you are copying just the first layer of the directory and just `COPY dir/` should do the thing